# Поменять значения каждого второго элемента матрицы на 0

Tags: python

Имеется матрица m на n. Нужно чтобы каждый 2 элемент матрицы был равен 0.

```
import random
m, n = 3, 3
matrix = [[random.randrange(0, 10) for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо  1 можете подставить все что угодно

```
matrix = [[1 if (i+j)%2 else 0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
```

ноль возвращается, когда сумма индексов кратна 2

Comment: А если потребуется как на рисунке (https://ibb.co/F65Wkck), заменить на 0 черные участки?

Comment: if not j%2 and i%2